# Insert multiple rows into sqlite database at once

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I want to insert a multiple rows into sqlite database using a single insert statement.

In Node JS the sqlite3 library allows us to do that referred from [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/insert/).

But in this tutorial only one single column is there, I'm facing problem while inserting rows with multiple columns.

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();


// opening the database connection
let db = new sqlite3.Database('CSVtoDB_CSVParse//sample.db');

var parser = csv.parse({delimiter: ','}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);    
    languages = data;
    let placeholders = languages.map((language) => '(?,?)').join(',');
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO sample VALUES ' + placeholders;

    // output the INSERT statement
    console.log(sql);

    db.run(sql, languages, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log(`Rows inserted ${this.changes}`);
    });

});

fs.createReadStream('CSVtoDB_CSVParse/sample1.csv').pipe(parser);
```

What I'm getting in the data object after parsing the CSV looks like this,

```
[ [ 'id', 'name' ],
  [ '1', 'A' ],
  [ '2', 'B' ],
  [ '3', 'C' ],
  [ '4', 'D' ],
  [ '5', 'E' ],
  [ '6', 'F' ],
  [ '7', 'G' ],
  [ '8', 'H' ],
  [ '9', 'I' ],
  [ '10', 'J' ] ]
```

But after the insertion my database table's data appearing like this,

```
sqlite> select * from sample;
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Output:

```
  [ '1', 'A' ],
  [ '2', 'B' ],
  [ '3', 'C' ],
  [ '4', 'D' ],
  [ '5', 'E' ],
  [ '6', 'F' ],
  [ '7', 'G' ],
  [ '8', 'H' ],
  [ '9', 'I' ],
  [ '10', 'J' ] ]
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)
Rows inserted 11
```

Anyone faced issue like this?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It's simpler programmatically to just to a bunch of one row inserts all as one transaction.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the output of your code. Is there an error or does it report the number of inserted rows properly? How is your `sample` table defined? You are trying to insert a value `id` into the column named "id". If that column is defined as a numeric type, this will raise an error.

Comment: I have added the output, it is not showing any error though the data format of ID is integer in the database.

Comment: You need to flatten that Array of Arrays. You have `[[a]]` and the function takes `[a]`.

Comment: If you make sure your input data is safe you should be able to do insert into sample values ('1','A'),('2','B') ....and so on. Placeholders are not mandatory.

Answer (score -2):

TO insert the username and password into the SqliteDB using Node js

**login.html**

```
<form action="auth" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
<input type="submit">   
</form>
```

**login.js**

```
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();//getting the Sqlite3 DB
    var express = require('express');//require the Express framework
    var session = require('express-session');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var path = require('path');
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./NodeTest.db');//getting the DataBase from Databasename
    var app = express();
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());    
    app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
    });
    app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {     
        var username = request.body.username;//getting the username from the request
        var password = request.body.password;//getting the password from the request
    db.run('Insert into Credentials(Username,Password) Values(?),(?)',[username,password],function(error){});
    response.end();
    });
    app.listen(3000);//port number is mentioned
```

Comment: this is not what the question was about